# How does kmean calculate data from different partitions?

Tags: apache-spark, k-means, rdd

When we use spark to do Kmeans, we should separate data into several partitions. Then decide k centers,and make k groups by calculating distances to the centers. And then repeat above step until we can find stable groups. 
Now, I want to know how the Kmeans MLib pick up k centers from different partitions and how it calculates distances of all data points from the partitions. Does it only consider data points from the same partition and re-partition after making groups? It will be helpful explaining this by using examples. For example, k = 4 and we have 2 partitions. Or k = 2 and we have 4 partitions.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's worth reading the [implementation of kmeans in mllib](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/clustering/KMeans.scala). It's quite short and not too difficult to understand.

At no point is there any need to repartition the data in kmeans - the partitions stay the same throughout the entire calculation.

A simplified version of what's going on. For each iteration of k means, the first being with already chosen centroids:

1. Iterate through each partition of the data, and for each point find the closest centroid. For each partition, recalculate the new centroids.
2. Merge the results for each partition back together. E.g. if partition 1 has contributed 4 points to centroid 1, and has a new centroid of (1.0, 2.0), and partition 2 has contributed 10 points to centroid 1, and has a new centroid of (2.0, 5.0), then merging them together gives: `(4 x 1.0 + 10 x 2.0, 4 x 2.0 + 10 x 5.0) / 14 = (1.71, 4.14)`.  These are the updated centroids for this iteration, which are fed back into step 1.